# Progressbar patterns (Eclipse)

Tags: design-patterns, eclipse, aspect-oriented

I've struggled quite a bit with Eclipse and progress-monitors to try to have good progressbars which report useful progress information to the user. Inevitably the code gets cluttered with lots of things like

```
if (monitor.isCancelled())
    return;

...

lengthyMethodCall(monitor.newChild(10));
```

and all over the place I need to pass a `IProgressMonitor` as an argument to my methods. This is bad, for several reasons:

1. The code gets cluttered with lots of code which is not relevant to what the function actually does.
2. I need to manually guesstimate which parts of the code takes time, and which parts do not.
3. It interacts badly with automated tests; where much of the information which goes into a progressbar instead should be logged for later inspection.

Is there a way out of this? Are there tools which can help me out with one or more of these problems? Should I be looking at Aspect-Oriented Programming tools, or are there other alternatives?

Comment: for point 3 can't you create your own IProgressMonitor (which you should be able to as it's an interface) which logs the calls to it and pass that into the method

Comment: Yes, I can. But I still consider it a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

> The code gets cluttered with lots of code which is not relevant to what the function actually does.

Sounds like Java run time exceptions. :-)  I guess one way out of the `IProgressMonitor` mess is to wrap up all of your "batch" processing into `Job`s (org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs).

> I need to manually guesstimate which parts of the code takes time, and which parts do not.

Not really.  You can wrap any code in a `Job`.  If it executes quickly, you won't even see the progress monitor popup.  If it takes time to process, then it should be a `Job` anyway.

> It interacts badly with automated tests; where much of the information which goes into a progressbar instead should be logged for later inspection.

ratchet freak already answered this in his comment.  You can write your own implementation of `IProgressMonitor` that logs the information you wish.

Comment: I'm not making myself clear. The problem is how to know how to divide the total progress monitor "ticks" among the subtasks. Say that I have a method which takes an `IProgressMonitor` and calls three methods. I don't want to guess how many ticks each call should get (when using `SubMonitor#newChild()`, for example).

Comment: @JesperE: You have two options.  Set all of the totalWork values to IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN, and leave all of your monitors indeterminate.  Or, you can set all of the totalWork values to IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN, and measure the amount of time your three methods takes.

Comment: If I wanted a concrete solution or workaround to this particular problem I would be asking on stackoverflow.com. I'm more interested  in thinking "outside the box" here, and not necessarily limit myself to what is technically possible with current APIs in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could annotate each method with custom annotation and then process those annotations.

or maybe you could log the last execution time of those methods and then estimate time based on that.

Comment: Your answer starts to address some of the OP's concerns, but does not do so fully.  Consider [edit]ing your answer and providing more details.